# How to capture the barcode using camera stream in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

How to capture the barcode using camera stream in visualforce page? My requirement is, from visualforce page we need to open a camera in mobile device and i will show the barcode. with out capturing the barcode need to get the barcode value when scan  the picture with picture. can anybody help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to integrate your application with a 3rd party system. Salesforce does not have any such inbuilt functionality to scan the barcode.

A few days back I stumbled upon [quaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/) library which is an awesome library to scan barcodes using just javascript. There are already a bunch of artifacts out there to use this library with Visualforce